# Show that $y_n=1+rx_1+r^2x_2+\cdots+r^nx_n$ is Cauchy given $x_n$ is bounded and $|r|<1$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $r\in\mathbb{R}$ be a fixed real number such that $|r|<1$ and $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence of real number. Consider $(y_n)$ such that $y_n:=1+rx_1+r^2x_2+\cdots+r^nx_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Show that $(y_n)$ is Cauchy by definition.

My attempt:

$\forall\epsilon>0$, we want to show that $\exists H\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n,m\ge H$, we have $|y_n-y_m|<\epsilon$.

W.L.O.G, $n\ge m$, take $n=m+k$, then

$$
\begin{align}
|y_n-y_m|&=|r|^{m+1}|\sum_{i=1}^kr^{i-1}x_{m+i}|\\
&<|\sum_{i=1}^kr^{i-1}x_{m+i}|\\
&\le\sum_{i=1}^k|r^{i-1}x_{m+i}|\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^k|r^{i-1}x_{m+i}|\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^k|r|^{i-1}|x_{m+i}|\\
&\le M\sum_{i=1}^k|r|^{i-1}\\
&=M\frac{1-|r|^k}{1-|r|}\\
\end{align}
$$

I am stuck here. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: **Hint :** Use the boundedness of $(x_n)$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks for your hint. Rectified and got it now.

Comment: Now do the same but keep the $|r|^{m+1}$, and see how this allows you to define the "good" $H$.

Comment: Yes, keep the $|r|^m$ and then use $1-|r|^k<1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $r=0$, the sequence $y_n=1$ is a constant, hence it is Cauchy. Next, we assume $r\ne 0$. Let $m=n+k$

> $$|y_n-y_m|=|r|^{n+1}|\sum_{i=1}^kr^{i-1}x_{n+i}|$$

Note, you **cannot** drop $|r|^{m+1}$ term, which is the key to complete the proof. If you keep this term, by doing the same derivation as you did above, you will get

$$|y_n-y_m|\le |r|^{n+1}M\frac{1-|r|^k}{1-|r|}$$

Since $0<|r|<1$, define $M_1=\frac{M}{1-|r|}$, we get

$$\begin{align}|y_n-y_m|&\le |r|^{n+1}M\frac{1-|r|^k}{1-|r|}\\
\\
&<|r|^n\cdot\frac{M}{1-|r|}=|r|^n M_1\end{align}$$

So we can take $$H=\frac{\ln(\epsilon/M_1)}{\ln |r|}$$

Therefore,

$$\forall n>H\Longrightarrow|y_m-y_n|<\epsilon$$

Answer (score -1):

$y_n=1+rx_1+r^2x_2+\cdots+r^nx_n$. Let $N$ such that $|x_i|\le N$ for all $i$ so we have
$$|y_n|= |1+rx_1+r^2x_2+\cdots+r^nx_n|\le 1+|Nr||1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^n|=1+|Nr|\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$ so $|y_n|$ tends to $1+|Nr|(\frac{1}{1-|r|})$ when $n\to+\infty$. Since the same goes for $|y_m|$ it follows that $|y_n-y_m|\to 0$ when $m,n\to+\infty$ (*because the sum is continuous*).

Comment: You get that $|y_n|$ converges to a limit that depends on $N$, but $N$ is not uniquely determined... There is a flaw somewhere (*hint :* you must have confused a $\leq$ sign with an $=$ sign).